# Applying JQuery effect when ember-data has finished loading and element is rendered

Tags: ember.js

I have a list of items that I want to make draggable. I am using ember-data to get the items from my API and then render them in a view with an ArrayController. I can successfully load the items and render them but I don't know where or when to put the JQuery draggable function.

I have tried using didInsertElement on my view but this is triggered when the view is rendered and not when the items are loaded. I have also tried to put an observer on my ArratController to run the code when the array length changes (i.e when an element is added to the array) None of these things worked.

Any ideas?

My JS code:

```
var REVISION = 9; 

// Application namespace
var App = Ember.Application.create({
    ApplicationView: Ember.View.extend({
        templateName:  'application',
        classNames: ['application-view']
    }),
    ApplicationController: Ember.Controller.extend(),
    RewardsView:  Em.View.extend({
        templateName:  'rewards',
        click: function(event) {
            console.log(event);
            //window.location.href = event
        },
        didInsertElement: function() {
            this.$(".draggable").draggable();
        }
    }),
    RewardsController:  Em.ArrayController.extend({
        rewardAdded: function() {
        $(".draggable").draggable({
            cursor: 'move',          // sets the cursor apperance
            revert: 'invalid',       // makes the item to return if it isn't placed into droppable
            revertDuration: 900,     // duration while the item returns to its place
        });
        }.observes('length')
    }),
    ready: function(){
        console.log("Created App namespace");
    },
    Router: Ember.Router.extend({
        goToRewards:  Ember.Route.transitionTo('root.rewards'),
        root:  Ember.Route.extend({
            index:  Ember.Route.extend({
                route:  '/',
            }),
            rewards:  Ember.Route.extend({
                route: '/rewards',
                enter: function ( router ){
                  console.log("The rewards sub-state was entered.");
                },
                connectOutlets:  function(router, context){
                  router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('content','rewards', App.store.findAll(App.Rewards));
                }
            }),
        })
    })
});

App.Rewards = DS.Model.extend({
    provider: DS.attr('string'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    discount: DS.attr('string'),
    img: DS.attr('string'),
    video: DS.attr('string'),
    price: DS.attr('string'),
    available_quantity: DS.attr('string'),

    didLoad: function() {
        console.log('model loaded', this);
    }
});

App.store = DS.Store.create({
    revision: REVISION,
    adapter: DS.DjangoTastypieAdapter.extend({
      serverDomain: "http://example.com",
      namespace: "api/v1"
    }),
});

// Start!
App.initialize();
```

My handlebars template:

```
{% handlebars "rewards" %}
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span6">
    <div class="box paint color_7">
      <div class="title">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <h4> Available Rewards </h4>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- End .title -->
      <div class="content">
        <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
          {{#each reward in controller}}
            <div class="draggable accordion-group">
              {{#with reward}}
                {{#if isLoaded}}
                  <div class="accordion-heading"> 
                    <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" {{bindAttr href="reward.id"}}> {{name}} {{id}} </a> 
                  </div>
                  <div {{bindAttr id="reward.id"}} class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px; ">
                    <div class="accordion-inner"> {{description}} </div>
                  </div>
                {{else}}
                    Loading...
                {{/if}}
              {{/with}}
            </div>
          {{/each}}

        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End .content --> 
    </div>
    <!-- End .box --> 
  </div>
{% endhandlebars%}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `findQuery` instead of `findAll`

```
router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('content','rewards',App.store.findQuery(App.Rewards));
```

You get the property `isLoaded` for the content, now you can add observer on `isLoaded` property to run your required functionality as follows

```
startDraggableFunctionality: function(){
  if(this.get('content.isLoaded'){
    /*Your code goes here...*/
  }
}.observes('content.isLoaded')
```

**After Rendering + Data loaded**
Inside the view add the following method as follows

```
View
```

```
//This method will be executed when the view has finished rendering
afterRender: function(){
  this.get('controller').set("viewRendered", true);
}
```

```
Controller
```

```
viewRendered: false, //set it to false initially
startDraggableFunctionality: function(){
  if(this.get('content.isLoaded') && this.get('viewRendered')){
    /*Your code goes here...*/
  }
}.observes('content.isLoaded', 'viewRendered')
```

This way if the view renders before loading content, `isLoaded` make sures that function will be executed only after data has been loaded & vice-versa

Comment: I have just tried this but it still doesn't work. I can confirm that this functionality runs after everything is loaded but apparently not after the views are rendered. So I cannot attach the functionality.

Comment: didInsertElement is executed when the element is inserted into the DOM not when it is rendered so try afterRender method instead & let me know if that worked

Comment: No, afterRender didn't do the trick either. As a matter of fact it ran before the content was loaded.

Comment: Ok, I tried it but here's the thing. It works if what I want to drag is the .content div. However, if I want to drag the individual items in the view it doesn't work. The problem is the same. The view is rendered but the array elements are still not loaded in time from ember-data.

Comment: Maybe the solution (and more Emeber-y approach) is to create sub-views for the items and use your solution on these sub-views.

Comment: hmm...if could make some sort of fiddle that'd help alot because if possible we can try using Ember.ContainerView for managing childviews

Comment: I'll try this and get back to you. Marked as accepted cz it works for people that follow the Ember way:)

Comment: Also accept the answer if you think the answer solved your question... I'd suggest you to go through http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ContainerView.html and see some examples related to it

Comment: Override didInsertView method as mentioned here http://mavilein.github.io/javascript/2013/08/01/Ember-JS-After-Render-Event/