# Do something after connectOutlet is loaded and rendered

Tags: ember.js

I'd like to do something (loading ads, do some statistics, etc.) after `connectOutlet("blog")` has loaded its data (`blogController.isLoaded`) and finished rendering (`view.afterRender` / `childViews.afterRender`).

Anything like `connectOutlet("blogs").isEverythingReady().then("Hurray, the user probably sees all the posts in his browser right now!")`?

Any hope? Any plans?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788194/applying-jquery-effect-when-ember-data-has-finished-loading-and-element-is-rende/13797154#13797154 Check the answer

Comment: Thanks, interesting, but what if I have child views and hasMany data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by observing `isLoaded` on the controllers that I need. When their `isLoaded` are true, I execute my ads, statistics and so on in a `setTimeout(250)`, assuming that 250ms is enough time for the browser to render my "page" after the data has returned from the server.